# Facebook Share Not Showing Description and Image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I have working with a project and i added a share button to product page, when i click on share it only showing the link of the site on fb share box no other infos showing
my home page can share successfully

**this is ok**

http://smartbetty.com

i added some og tags but no luck

**here is my issue url**

```
http://smartbetty.com/index.php/frontend/campaigns/single/882/Fantastic-Deal-24-for-a-Stunning-Pair-of-Pearls-Meet-Silver-Drop-Earrings-Valued-at-150
```

**and when i debug it on face book debugger it gives follow results**

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsmartbetty.com%2Findex.php%2Ffrontend%2Fcampaigns%2Fsingle%2F882%2FFantastic-Deal-24-for-a-Stunning-Pair-of-Pearls-Meet-Silver-Drop-Earrings-Valued-at-150
```

i play this with hours but no luck
have any one know whats the wrong with this
thank you

Comment: Open Graph! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: On your debug page look at what it says under __Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed__

Comment: ya i saw that,but browser didn't gives moves tempory 302 error, how the facebook returns it, and where is the point can i start this fixing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger’s response is quite clear, isn’t it?

> URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.

Your page sends a 302 redirect – to the same adress! And if that is followed, it’s the same redirect again … and again … and again.

How do you expect any tool to extract data from a page that behaves like that …?

Since it’s not doing that when requesting the page in a “real” browser, you’re obviously messing things up on the server side somehow – maybe trying to set a cookie, and then redirect to the same adress, expecting to have the cookie value to work with (which you don’t have with a tool like FB’s scraper that doesn’t accept or send cookies), or something like that …

Comment: when i access using browser i can see all things, but why the facebook gives 302 page. cant understand that :(

Comment: Well, disable cookies in your browser (and delete existing ones for your page), and then try to load it – same issue, endless redirects, until the browser finally gives up. So you’ll have to do some debugging/reading the docs on the system you’re using, and try and figure out _why_ it’s behaving that way and how to disable that. And beat the programmer over the head with something heavy, because _assuming_ cookies will work and provide no fallback if they don’t is just plain stupid & amateurish :-)

Comment: :) great, but in google plus this shows nicely
http://smartbetty.com/index.php/frontend/campaigns/single/882/Fantastic-Deal-24-for-a-Stunning-Pair-of-Pearls-Meet-Silver-Drop-Earrings-Valued-at-150
i'try this way